# How to chain a command after sudo su?

Tags: sudo, bash-alias

The idea is simple, for example:

```
alias foo='sudo su foo && cd /tmp'
```

However, it does not execute commands after switching users. In this case, it switches users but does not cd into /tmp.

Comment: have you read `man su`? the `-c` option might be what you are searching for. Note that it'll exit back to the invoking user after the commands are executed.

Comment: @Fiximan thanks, although I don't want to exit back to the invoking user.

Comment: Well, if I add e.g. `; bash` or `; su` at the end of my commands, I get an error (which I cannot interpret), but stay logged in as `root`. Doing things that throw out errors might not be nice, but maybe fulfil your needs.